# Does boost or C++11 have identical mutex with tbb::queuing_mutex and tbb::spin_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, tbb

Just wondering if boost or C++11 have identical mutex with `tbb::queuing_mutex` and `tbb::spin_mutex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the supported mutexes in the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

C++11 has the following:

- `mutex`
- `timed_mutex`
- `recursive_mutex`
- `recursive_timed_mutex`

Whether they are spin mutexes or queuing mutexes or something else is implementation dependent.